# Is my proof of the $|a||b|=|ab|$ property correct?

Tags: solution-verification, absolute-value

I want to show that $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $|a||b|=|ab|$. Is the proof I have come up with correct? Have I accounted for every possible case?

**Case 1, $a,b\ge0$**:

By definition, $|a|=a$ and $|b|=b$, thus we have $|a||b|=ab$.

$a,b\ge0$ implies that $ab\ge0$. Therefore, by definition, $|ab|=ab$.

So, $\forall a,b\ge0$, we have $|a||b|=|ab|$ $\blacksquare$

**Case 2, $a,b<0$**:

By definition, $|a|=-a$ and $|b|=-b$, thus we have $|a||b|=(-a)(-b)=ab$.

$a,b<0$ implies that $ab>0$. Therefore, by definition, $|ab|=ab$.

So, $\forall a,b<0$, we have $|a||b|=|ab|$ $\blacksquare$

**Case 3, $a\ge0,b<0$ & $a<0, b\ge 0$**:

First, consider the subcase $a\ge0$, $b<0$.

By definition, $|a|=a$, and $|b|=-b$. Therefore, $|a||b|=(a)(-b)=-ab$.

$a\ge0$, $b<0$ implies that $ab\le0$. Thus, by definition, $|ab|=-ab$.

So, $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a\ge 0, b<0$, we have $|a||b|=|ab|$.

Because multiplication is commutative, we can show that we have $|a||b|=|ab|$ for the subcase $a<0, b\ge0$ using essentially the exact same argument as above.

So, $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a\ge0, b<0$ or $a<0,b\ge0$, we have $|a||b|=|ab|$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks perfectly OK to me.

Comment: yeah, looks good to me too.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: @Shaun so next time I ask a question like this I should just use the absolute-value tag?

Comment: No. You need to explain what aspect you're struggling with. Verifying a whole proof is too broad. See the links in the tag wiki for details and a discussion.

Comment: @Shaun Ok I'll try to be more specific next time, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good!

You can also prove it using that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ for real $x$; this allows you to do it without separating cases:

$$|ab|=\sqrt{(ab)^2}=\sqrt{a^2b^2}=\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{b^2}=|a|\cdot|b|.$$

The advantage of this method is that (a generalisation of) it can be used to show that $|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|$ for *complex* $z$ and $w$.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this other definition but I will read up on it (I am using the piecewise definition). Thank you for the confirmation and additional info.

Comment: To get more familiar with it, compute $\sqrt{x^2}$ for $x=3$ and $x=-3$. You will see that $\sqrt{x^2}$ basically just removes negative signs (because $x^2$ is never negative).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there ever any advantage to using the piecewise definition then, if proofs seem a lot easier with this definition?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui the advantage is you don’t need to define square roots (and prove their corresponding properties). Defining square roots is a tricky business (you need to show every non-negative real number has a unique non-negative square root), and this relies on the completeness of the real numbers. Of course one could instead start with a more minimalistic definition, by only defining $\sqrt{x^2}$ for real $x$, rather than $\sqrt{a}$ for arbitrary $a\in[0,\infty)$, but this gives you essentially the piecewise definition so it is rather silly.

Comment: i.e it’s a question of where you want to move the ‘hard-work’: Do you want a simple definition and ‘tedious’ proof (piecewise) or do you want ‘tedious’ definition and simple proof (using square roots) :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok I see.. so I guess I'll stick to using the piecewise definition for now. Thanks.